# How I can sum all the values of a property in a Meteor collection?

Tags: mongodb, sum, meteor

For example :

```
Object {_id: "9g9ySxozSWn1", name: "test1", price: 1}
Object {_id: "9g9ySxozSWn2", name: "test2", price: 2}
Object {_id: "9g9ySxozSWn3", name: "test3", price: 3}
Object {_id: "9g9ySxozSWn4", name: "test3", price: 6}
Object {_id: "9g9ySxozSWn5", name: "test3", price: 3}
```

What is the best way to sum up all the price where for example the name is test3?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if you don't want to use Underscore:

```
var total = 0;

MyCollection.find({name:"test3"}).map(function(doc) {
  total += doc.price;
});
```

Comment: Two things: 1) Meteor's `.find()` returns a cursor, so it's better to do `.find().fetch()` as in Akshat's answer. 2) This is a misuse of `map`, better to use `forEach`. Or even better: `total = MyCollect.find({ name: 'test3' }).fetch().map(item => item.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b)`

Comment: Yeah, i wrote this answer a long time ago when Meteor was still very much in flux. If I remember well I used `map()` because cursors didn't have `forEach()` yet, or maybe I was just still a noob at functional programming lol

Answer (score 2):

Is this on the client? At the moment aggregation queries aren't yet directly supported, minimongo even with an aggregation query would still do a localized map-reduce in one way or another:

```
total = _.reduce(_.map(MyCollection.find({name:"test3"}).fetch(), 
                function(doc) {
                  //map
                  return doc.price
                }), 
                function(memo, num){ 
                  //reduce
                  return memo + num;
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Note the reduce function needs an initial value of memo, which you provide as a final argument (eg. ... `return memo+num; }, 0);`. See http://underscorejs.org/#reduce for details.